# on iOS how to judge a textfield complete input

Tags: ios, textfield

I want to search some words after user complete input,
I have try this selector, but its called at every input changed.

```
#pragma mark   textFieldValueChanged
- (void)inputSearchTextChanged:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.text.length == 0) {
       self.searchView.tipsView.hidden = NO;
     } else {
       self.searchView.tipsView.hidden = YES;
    }
    if (self.searchView.lySelectView.selectState == LYTabSelectOptionLeft) {
        [self searchTagWithTagTitle:textField.text];
    } else {
        [self searchPeopleWithTagTitle:textField.text];
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want `textFieldDidEndEditing` ?

Comment: I didn't express clearly， i don't want the textfield end editing , just like: you want to input @"hotdog" , first, you quickly input "hot", after a while, you continue to input "dog". i want get the event that you input "hot". how i could ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. More details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:). You have to implement the method *-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextFiled*)textfield)* in your ViewController.

```
 -(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextFiled*)textfield)
 {
     if (textField.text.length == 0) {
       self.searchView.tipsView.hidden = NO;
     } else {
       self.searchView.tipsView.hidden = YES;

    if (self.searchView.lySelectView.selectState == LYTabSelectOptionLeft) {
        [self searchTagWithTagTitle:textField.text];
    } else {
        [self searchPeopleWithTagTitle:textField.text];
    }
}
```

Asssign your ViewController as the delegate:

```
self.textField.delegate = self; //self is the ViewController.
```

**Later edit after clarifications:**

You want an event when the user has stopped typing: you can simulate this event with a timer.

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

 ....

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)strin {
    if (self.timer != nil) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }

    self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(eventNeeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    return YES;
}

-(void) eventNeeded{
    NSLog(@"User has stopped typing.");
}
```

Comment: I didn't express clearly， i don't want the textfield end editing , just like: you want to input @"hotdog" , first, you quickly input "hot", after a while, you continue to input "dog".

Comment: i want get the event that you input "hot".    how i could ?

Comment: You can start a NSTimer in inputSearchTextChanged and invalidate the timer each time a character is written. If the timer expires you will have your event.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextFiled*)textfield) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set delegate of textfield and try below delegate method


-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextFiled*)textfield)
     {
         if (textField.text.length == 0) {
           self.searchView.tipsView.hidden = NO;
         } else {
           self.searchView.tipsView.hidden = YES;

        if (self.searchView.lySelectView.selectState == LYTabSelectOptionLeft) {
            [self searchTagWithTagTitle:textField.text];
        } else {
            [self searchPeopleWithTagTitle:textField.text];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't express clearly， i don't want the textfield end editing , just like: you want to input @"hotdog" , first, you quickly input "hot", after a while, you continue to input "dog".                   
i want get the event that you input "hot". how i could ?